# readLines converts hyphen (-) to \x

Tags: regex, r

readLines is converting hyphens, "-", in a .txt file to "\x". Why? I have tried toying with the encoding , but without sucess. I have also tried using gsub and str_replace_all (stringr package) to replace the "\x" on the back end with an actual hyphen, "-".

```
record <- readLines(con="~/Dropbox/WisconsinLeg/input/WI_1895.txt", encoding="UTF-8")
```

I can't attach a .txt file to try reading in, but here is some sample data once it is read into R using the proceeding line of code:

```
c("IN ASSEMBLY.", "JOURNAL OF PROCEEDINGS", "\xd1 OF THE-", "FORTY-SECOND SESSION","\xd1 OF THE \xd1", "WISCONSIN LEGISLATURE.")
```

One variation of the code I tried to replace the "\x" with:

```
record <- str_replace_all(record, pattern="\x", replace="-", fixed=FALSE)
```

Also, for my edification, what does "\x" mean? Is it just a hyphen or is it some sort of special character?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is how the text looks in the .txt file:

IN ASSEMBLY.

JOURNAL OF PROCEEDINGS

— OF THE-

FORTY-SECOND SESSION

— OF THE —

WISCONSIN LEGISLATURE.

18QS.

Hence why I supposed that it was a hyphen. Thanks to the responders.

Comment: It's not `\x`, it's `\xHH` where `HH` is two hexadecimal characters.  `\xd1` means "the character with an ASCII value of 0xD1 (hex)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confused. It's not "\x". The display of "\xd1" is actually the display of a single character that does not have a representation in your font. It is a non-printing character (probably a "long dash")  that is being displayed as an escape sequence. To get rid of it, you need to use gsub with extra backslashes because both R and regex use backslash as their escape character"

```
 gsub("\\\xd1", "_", x)
#[1] "IN ASSEMBLY."           "JOURNAL OF PROCEEDINGS" "_ OF THE-"             
#[4] "FORTY-SECOND SESSION"   "_ OF THE _"             "WISCONSIN LEGISLATURE."
```